# word vba: documents.add: put this new document on top

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using VBA for MS Word. I created a macrofile (docm) to create a new word-document using `documents.add`....

I want to switch from my macro-document to my new created document on the screen:

```
Sub test()
    Dim MacroDocument As Document
    Set MacroDocument = ActiveDocument
    Dim newDocument As Document
    Set newDocument = Documents.Add

    'try to show my macroDocument on the windows screen,
    MacroDocument.Select
    stop
    ' now to the new document
    newDocument.Select

End Sub
```

Why doesn't it work?

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

`document.Select` just selects the document but doesn't displays it.

Use `MacroDocument.Activate` and `newDocumente.Activate` instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a document, the new document automatically becomes the active one and will replace the current one on your screen. Therefore, in most cases the task isn't to make it show but to keep the previous one on top. In such a case making the new document invisible is one of the options you might want to consider.
`Set NewDocument = Documents.Add(Visible:=False)`